# Проблемы с внешним сетевым устройством

Tags: сеть

Мой старый вай-фай адаптер на 2.4 ггц работал достаточно медленно, поэтому я решил приобрести новый с возможностью передачи сигнала на частоте 5.0 ггц. Однако новое устройство никак не вставало на комп даже с официальными драйверами. Вопрос: если исключить поломки внутри адаптера, это может быть несовместимость с материнской платой?

Хотя вопрос не совсем соответствует тематике ресурса, здесь явно есть знающие люди. Поэтому, если можете ответить про аппаратную совместимость сетевых адаптеров и других устройств, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Фраза "никак не вставало" не несёт никакой информации и не имеет никакого смысла. Какие ошибки пишет? Отображается ли в диспетчере устройств?

Comment: А также хотя бы названия чудоустройства, иногда нужно даже версию железа точную знать, ось